# (SpringBoot + React.js) Whitelabel error page - Resource not found

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, react-router

I ran into a problem, I wrote a page on the React to reset the password, when I run only the React application and click on the link `127.0.0.1:8080/user/resetPassword/53442` everything is displayed well. As soon as I run in bundle with Spring Boot, whitelabel error page type = 404 appears. And in the Spring log I get this:

```
GET "/ user / resetPassword / afsa11", parameters = {}

Mapped to `ResourceHttpRequestHandler [URL [file: C: / Users / Jake Morgan / IdeaProjects / react-invasion / build / index.html]]

Resource not found
```

I did not write any controller for this patch and do not use model view, because I don’t need it there, I make a request to another point after entering the form through Axios.

Most likely I missed something and forgot some setting.

Maybe `doFilter`?

My `App.js` - React:

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Header from './Components/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import PasswordResetPage from './Pages/PasswordResetPage';
import Test from './Components/Test';

function App() {
 return (
<>
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/vasua/" component={Test}/>
        <Route path="/user/resetPassword/:id" component={PasswordResetPage} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
  <Header />
</>
);
}

export default App;
```

My `MvcSecurityConfig`:

```java
@Value("${path.frontend}")
private String frontendPath;
@Value("${frontendStaticResourcesPathPatterns}")
private String[] frontendStaticResourcesPathPatterns;
private static final String BASE_API_PATH = "/";

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    String pathToFrontend = "file:" + this.frontendPath;
    String pathToIndexHTML = pathToFrontend + "index.html";

    registry
            .addResourceHandler(frontendStaticResourcesPathPatterns)
            .setCachePeriod(0)
            .addResourceLocations(pathToFrontend);

    registry.addResourceHandler("/", "/**")
            .setCachePeriod(0)
            .addResourceLocations(pathToIndexHTML)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                    if (resourcePath.startsWith(BASE_API_PATH) || resourcePath.startsWith(BASE_API_PATH.substring(1))) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location : null;
                }
            });

}
```

My web security config:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                    "/user/forgotPassword",
                    "/user/resetPassword",
                    "/user/resetPassword/*",
                    "/user/resetPassword/**/",
                    "/api/auth/*",
                    "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/static/**",
                    "/manifest.json",
                    "/logo192.png",
                    "/index.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().disable();

        http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Folder:

```
    C:/Users/Jake Morgan/IdeaProjects/react-invasion/build/
|   asset-manifest.json
|   favicon.ico
|   index.html
|   logo192.png
|   logo512.png
|   manifest.json
|   robots.txt
|   tree.txt
|   
\---static
    +---css
    |       2.818011ed.chunk.css
    |       2.818011ed.chunk.css.map
    |       main.6745c9b9.chunk.css
    |       main.6745c9b9.chunk.css.map
    |       
    +---js
    |       2.d6a0ce6c.chunk.js
    |       2.d6a0ce6c.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
    |       2.d6a0ce6c.chunk.js.map
    |       3.c6fb18dc.chunk.js
    |       3.c6fb18dc.chunk.js.map
    |       main.a7a27014.chunk.js
    |       main.a7a27014.chunk.js.map
    |       runtime-main.197b0595.js
    |       runtime-main.197b0595.js.map
    |       
    \---media
            Invasion-Project.0dba6a23.exe
            mov.41f2b828.mp4
            start.e3a0d02b.png
            x.85f9f2a1.svg
```

Application.properties

```
#Frontend
path.frontend = C:/Users/Jake Morgan/IdeaProjects/react-invasion/build/
frontendStaticResourcesPathPatterns=/**/*.css,/**/*.html,/**/*.js,/**/*.jsx,/**/*.png,/**/*.ttf,/**/*.woff,/**/*.woff2,/**/*.ico,/**/*.jpg,/**/*.mp4,/**/*.svg,manifest.json
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,file:${path.frontend}
```

**UPDATE**

I added HashRouter to my React.js instead of BrowserRouter and now the page opens, but at this address:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

127.0.0.1:8080/#/user/resetPassword/412
What is this # sign and can it be removed?

Comment: Why do you have a custom jwtfilter? Please read the jwt chapter in the spring security documentation how to implement the handling of jwts properly, spring security has had jwtsupport since 2018

Comment: This functionality is not used, the question is different

Comment: @ДжейкМорган Does this file `C: / Users / Jake Morgan / IdeaProjects / react-invasion / build / index.html` exists? You mapped the URL to this file.

Comment: "127.0.0.1:8080/" opens fine, the problem is only with the pages

Comment: index.html exists

Comment: the log says the files in not in the build folder, where is the index.html. Please update your question will your full folder structure that shows where all the projects and resources are placed. Clearly you are mixing up how things are loaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a problem

```
private static final String BASE_API_PATH = "/";
```

Correct:

```
private static final String BASE_API_PATH = "/api";
```